# How to Interpret the Inverted Question Mark via SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
 SELECT 'Hello Word... Test…' FROM DUAL
```

Running the above SQL query in Oracle developer gives me the following output:

[image]

**How can I maintain the special character in the output and prevent the inverted question mark to appear?**

The characterset of my Oracle database: WE81SO8859P1

Here is the list:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 levels to manage:

- database
- instance
- session (client)

Be careful of the parameters set on your sql client. You can check with the below query.

```
SELECT
  data.parameter "PARAMETERS",
  data.value "DATABASE PARAMETERS",
  inst.value "INSTANCE PARAMETERS",
  sess.value "SESSION PARAMETERS"
FROM
  nls_database_parameters data LEFT OUTER JOIN nls_instance_parameters inst
                                             ON(data.parameter = inst.parameter)
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN nls_session_parameters sess
                                            ON(data.parameter = sess.parameter)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: It's actually four levels: the font used in the UI must be capable of displaying the characters.